# Оправить ajax запрос на сервер в цикле

Tags: javascript

Как правильно остановить цикл и дождаться ответа от сервера?

Есть массив

const arr = [1, 2, 3];

Проходясь по нему в цикле

```
for(let i = 0;  i < arr.length; i++){
    ajaxFunction();
}
```

Как дождаться ответа перед повторным выполнением фукции?

Comment: Можно все функции сложить в массив и вызвать `Promise.all()`

Comment: Что есть `ajaxFunction()`?

Answer (score 1):

Вариант 1:

```js
const f = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve('Tik'), 1000));


const af = [
  f,
  f,
  f,
];

async function start() {
  for (const item of af) {
    const r = await item();
    console.log(r);
  }
}

start();
```

Вариант 2:

```js
const f = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve('Tik'), 3000));


const af = [
  f(),
  f(),
  f(),
];

Promise.all(af).then(() => console.log('Finished'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете сделать свою функцию асинхронной добавив `async/await`.
И затем вызвать её с например в самовызывающейся функции.

```
let ajaxFunction = async () => { await fetch('google.com').then(res => console.log(res))}

const arr = [1, 2, 3];

(async () =>{
for(let i = 0;  i < arr.length; i++){
    console.log('new');
    await ajaxFunction();
}
})();
```

Comment: Не работает. Сделайте снипет.